# Implementing a non continuous loss function

Tags: loss-function, catboost

I am trying to implement a custom loss function with the following reasoning:

1. If the predicted value is higher then the target then the loss ther difference
2. If the predicted value is lower than the target, the loss is constant and represents a loss of the guess (I.e. if the target value is 10, it makes no difference if I guessed 1 or 2, the result is the same)

I am unsure of how to do it is catboost, as it requires a loss function to return the derivatives and would apprciate any help on the matter.
Thanks

Tried to implement it

Comment: Hi Ron! I see this is your first post, welcome! I see you shared that you tried implement it. Could you share how you tried to implement it so far and what problem(s) you ran into?

Comment: Hi
Thank you for replying

Sure, though I am unsure that what I tried made sense.

What I want is to have a constant loss value of 10 for every time the algorithm predicts below requested value and an increasing value of prediction-actual when ever it predicts above

I tried to implement in using ? Metric and Objective classes, but could not figure out how to do so